# Angular Js how to refresh a new factory instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-factory

I am using a factory to get list of folders and display it in the front end. Also in the front end i have form where i can add new folder to the existing list. After adding a folder i want to refresh my factory instance and display the updated folder list.

// factory

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('archiveService', ['$http', 'ApiUrl', function($http, ApiUrl) {
var archiveService = function() {
    this.repos = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.page = 0;
};
archiveService.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;
    var url = ApiUrl.url + '/folders/?page=' + this.page;
    $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        this.repos = res.data;
        if (items.repos == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.page += 1
        this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(data) {
    }.bind(this));
};
return {
    archiveService: archiveService,
}
```

}]);

// this is my controller

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('archiveModalController', ['$rootScope', '$scope','archiveService', function($rootScope, $scope, archiveService) {

// I want to refresh this and show new data on update

    $scope.archivelist = new archiveService.archiveService();

}])
```

I would like to know how can i refresh so i can get the new updated data

$scope.archivelist = new archiveService.archiveService();

Answer (score 0):

Angular services follow the [singleton](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) pattern meaning the instantiation of a class is restricted to a single object.

Also, since you are using a factory:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('archiveService', [<dependencies>, function () {
    function nextPage() {
        //code here
    );

    return {
        nextPage: nextPage
    }

}]);
```

Then in your controller you simply:

```
archiveService.nextPage();
```

Seeing the variables in place I believe `nextPage` could simply receive the page as a parameter and since `repos` is an array I guess you meant to add the new fetched data to that array?
Which would be: 
`this.repos.push(res.data;)` instead of `this.repos = res.data`;

Point is, each time you want to request new data you should call the correct service/factory method from the controller.

So at your controller init, you only need:

```
(function init() {
    $scope.archivelist = archiveService.nextPage();
})();
```

Although like I stated, you should probably have an initial value like `nextPage(1)` and from there send the desired page you want to the factory method to be handled correctly.